# Verify recursive integrals $A_n=-5A_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$, where $A_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have the sequence

$$A_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5} dx$$

starting at $n=0$ and want to confirm that for all $n \geq 1$, 
$$A_n=-5A_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n}$$

I suspect I need to integrate by parts, especially noticing that the right term is $\int_0^1 x^{n-1} dx$, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to split it into u and dv. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note,

$$A_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{x+5} dx=\int_0^1 \frac{(x+5-5)x^{n-1}}{x+5} dx$$
$$=\int_0^1x^{n-1}dx -5\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{x+5} dx=\frac{1}{n}-5A_{n-1}$$